# MAAS and non-ubuntu images

Tags: windows, maas

Can I install an operating system other thsan Ubuntu using MAAS?

For example could I install Windows? Or Solaris?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, only Ubuntu is currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

Since MAAS 1.7 (released in November 2014) it supports more operating systems than just Ubuntu.

From the [release blog post](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/20/maas-1-7-one-maas-multiple-operating-systems/):

> Specifically, MAAS can now provision **Windows Server 2012 RT/Hyper-V, CentOS, RHEL, SLES, and OpenSUSE**. The installation is done using the same single-pass mechanism used to deploy Ubuntu, typically providing the user with a running system in under 8 minutes on an SSD (or around 25 minutes on an HDD).